# setting env vars and running an autosys command via java

Tags: java, batch-file, autosys

We are building a basic monitoring utility for autosys agents and one of the commands that tells us if the agent is active is "autoping -M ". Our current tool, already written by someone else is in Java and we need to add a new Class with this functionality.

The class needs to have a method that runs the autoping command and capture the output to a File. This is the current code i have

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class TestAgent 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        buildBatchFile();
    }

    public static void buildBatchFile() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String instanceName="ABM";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\autoping-batch.bat");
        writer.println("set AUTOSYS=\"D:\\PROGRA~2\\CA\\WORKLO~1\\autosys\"");
        writer.println("set AUTOROOT=\"D:\\PROGRA~2\\CA\\WORKLO~1\"");
        writer.println("set AUTOSERV="+instanceName);
        writer.println("set AUTOUSER=D:\\PROGRA~2\\CA\\WORKLO~1\\autouser."+instanceName);
        writer.println("set CASHCOMP(x86)=D:\\PROGRA~2\\CA\\SC");
        writer.println("set PATH=%AUTOSYS%\\bin;%PATH%");
        writer.println("autoping -M ALL >> D:\\autopingResults.txt");
        writer.close();
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c D:\\autoping-batch.bat");
    }
}
```

as can be seen, i am trying to create a batch file and run it, but the output does not get captured in the `autopingResults.txt` file. It is just blank.

Also I don't think the commands are actually getting executed. How do I debug this and is there a better way to set these environment variables on the fly (maybe use `System.setProperty`?) and run the `autoping` command?

Without the variables being set, `autoping` will return errors like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>autoping
Resource bundle is not available while looking for key="CAUAJM_E_80003".
```

With the variables set the output is below:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set AUTOROOT=D:\PROGRA~2\CA\WORKLO~1
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set AUTOSERV=ADK
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set AUTOSYS=D:\PROGRA~2\CA\WORKLO~1\autosys
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set AUTOUSER=D:\PROGRA~2\CA\WORKLO~1\autouser.ADK
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set PATH=%AUTOSYS%\bin;%PATH%
C:\WINDOWS\system32>autoping -M ALL

CAUAJM_I_50023 AutoPinging Machine [XXX.YYY.com]
CAUAJM_I_50025 AutoPing WAS SUCCESSFUL.
```